# Stopwords on SQL Server 2012 with compatibility 90

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How enable stopwords (noise words)  on SQL Server 2012 with compatibility level 90?

I can't create a full-text stoplist because we use compatibility level 90. When a database is upgraded to SQL Server 2012 from SQL Server 2005, the noise-word files are no longer used.

Comment: I don't think you can; under compatibility 90 on SQL 2012 you will use the system stop list as the old file system approach was deprecated. As the Resource database is read only when  tried ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST on my system it failed.

It may be your best approach is to move the FTS tables into a compatibility 100 DB which will let you have a noise words table in the db.

Comment: It must be test, but we aren't have time for it.